# Firebase: Uncaught Error: Query.equalTo: startAt() or equalTo() previously called

Tags: jquery, firebase

I found nothing when I tried to search this error on Google:
"Uncaught Error: Query.equalTo: startAt() or equalTo() previously called!".

(one result that says nothing)

I'm trying to select X children with name of Toni that are found before lastId.

for example:

```
Ref:
   -236feg262477
        name: "Toni"
   -9759jj900000
        name: "RVR"
   -969999999999
        name: "Toni"
   -777777777777
        name: "TTT"
   -553333333333
        name: "Toni"

Ref.orderByChild("name")
   .equalTo("Toni")
   .startAt(null, "-969999999999")
   .limitToFirst(1)
   .on('child_added', function (snapshot) {

        // do something...

});
```

But I get the error in the title of this topic.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Can you remove the `startAt` part and try ? Intuitively this looks like an ordering issue. i.e try re-arranging the way in which you're calling `equalTo` and other functions

Comment: It doesn't work.. I'm trying to find another solution.. I will notify if I will find something..

Comment: `.equalTo("Toni")` is shorthand for `.startAt("Toni").endAt("Toni")`. So you're essentially trying to order/filter by both `name` and `.priority`, which is not supported in Firebase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens when you call either `startAt(...)` `endAt(...)` or `equalTo(...)` in the same query. You can't do multiple, just one.

Below are two options to fix your example

```
Ref.orderByChild("name")
   .equalTo("Toni")
   .limitToFirst(1)
   .on('child_added', function (snapshot) {...})`
```

or

```
Ref.orderByChild("name")
   .startAt(null, "-969999999999")
   .limitToFirst(1)
   .on('child_added', function (snapshot) {...})`
```